# neural net sigmoid function "takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"

Tags: python, neural-network, matrix-multiplication, sigmoid

trying to forward propagate some data through a neural net

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Neural_Network(object):
def __init__(self):        
    #Define Hyperparameters
    self.inputLayerSize = 2
    self.outputLayerSize = 1
    self.hiddenLayerSize = 3

    #Weights (parameters)
    self.W1 = np.random.randn(self.inputLayerSize, self.hiddenLayerSize)
    self.W2 = np.random.randn(self.hiddenLayerSize, self.outputLayerSize)

def forward(self, X):
    #Propagate inputs though network
    self.z2 = np.dot(X, self.W1)
    self.a2 = self.sigmoid(self.z2)
    self.z3 = np.dot(self.a2, self.W2)
    yHat = self.sigmoid(self.z3) 
    return yHat

def sigmoid(z):
    # apply sigmoid activation function
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
```

When I run:
`NN = Neural_Network()
yHat = NN.forward(X)`

Why do I get the error:`TypeError: sigmoid() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

when I run:
`print NN.W1`

i get: `[[ 1.034435   -0.19260378 -2.73767483]
 [-0.66502157  0.86653985 -1.22692781]]`

(perhaps this is a problem with the numpy dot function returning too many dimensions?)

*note: i am running in jupyter notebook and `%pylab inline`

Comment: Are you studying ANNs through Stephen Welch's (_Welchlabs_) tutorials? I think I've already seen that code there.

Comment: yea, pure oversight on my part though

Comment: keep going, these tutorials are absolutely awesome! I myself learned a lot from them. You can also check out [this online book about ANNs](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com), it has many examples and very clean explanations.

Comment: thanks for the encouragement! :) and the reference (I have definitely come across this before and will revisit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `self` argument for the `sigmoid` function. `def sigmoid(z):` -> `def sigmoid(self, z):`. This `self.sigmoid(self.z3)` is effectively calling `sigmoid` with `self` as the first parameter and `self.z3` as the second.

(That or your code indentation is off which doesn't look likely since the code runs)